# How to open multiple e-mail client windows by window.open in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html/js code:

```
<button onclick="openWindows()">Open 3 e-mail windows</button>
<script>
      function openWindows(){
          window.open("mailto:asd@gmail.com","_self",'PopUp1');
          window.open("mailto:asd2@gmail.com","_self",'PopUp2');
          window.open("mailto:asd3@gmail.com","_self",'PopUp3');
      } 
</script>
```

This code should open 3 different e-mail client windows. In the IE and FF the code works correctly, but in Chrome only one (the last) window is displayed. Is there any browser independent solution which allows to open multiple windows all at once?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `"_self"` with `"_blank"`.

Beware - many browsers block popups by default.

Comment: I checked it before and the same result. I've allowed popups for testing.

Comment: I just did it on my localhost and it opened 3 windows

Comment: 3 Chrome windows have been opened or 3 e-mail client windows? In my case 3 Chrome windows are displayed, but only one Outlook window. In FF 3 Outlook windows are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. Changing it to `_blank` did not work for me (on chrome 43).

Instead I added a `setTimeout` to the mailto calls and it worked as expected.

Around 500ms between messages seems to work for me.

```
      setTimeout(function() {window.open("mailto:asd@gmail.com","_self",'PopUp1');}, 500);
      setTimeout(function() {window.open("mailto:asd2@gmail.com","_self",'PopUp2');}, 1000);
      setTimeout(function() {window.open("mailto:asd3@gmail.com","_self",'PopUp3');}, 1500);
```